# C++ using concrete virtual method of abstract base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a abstract base class with a mixture of pure and concrete virtual methods, e.g.:

```
template < class T > class A {
   public:
   A ( ) { }
   virtual ~A ( ) { }

   virtual void purefunc( const T & a, T & b ) const = 0;
   virtual T concretefunc ( const T & a ) { 
       T b;                 // requires new memory allocation for b
       purefunc( a, b ); 
       return b; 
   }
};
```

And a derived class which implements the pure virtual function, e.g.:

```
template < class T > class B : public A < T > {
   public:
   B ( T c ) : c_( c ) { }
   ~B ( ) { }

   void purefunc( const T & a, T & b ) const {
       b = c_ * a;              // uses memory of b without reallocation
   }

   private: T c_;
};
```

Could someone explain me how to call the concrete base method when I have an object of the child class, without typecasting it into a polymorphic pointer of the abstract base class (if at all possible):

```
int a = 2, b;
B< int > B_obj( 2 );
b = B_obj.concretefunc( a );  //!! doesn't work: 'no matching function for call'

B< int > * B_ptr = &B_obj;
b = B_ptr->concretefunc( a ); //!! doesn't work either: 'no matching function for call'

A< int > * A_ptr = &B_obj;
b = A_ptr->concretefunc( a ); //!! works, but explicit type casted isn't very intuitive
```

much obliged on any explanation or help!

EDIT: added public classifiers,
hmm, this dummy code works fine. will go check what's different in my actual code...

EDIT 2: found my problem: I used the same name for purefunc and concretefunc as overloads of each other. Hence if you write instead:

```
virtual void func( const T & a, T & b ) const = 0;
virtual T func ( const T & a ) { ... }
```

It gives the compile errors I was having trouble with. Not sure why overloads are not working  while different methods are...

Comment: Your updated code compiles for me. Please don't post code that you haven't bothered to test!

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought I had represented my real problem in an appropriate reduced example. And indeed, the example does compile. This was the difference: in my actual code purefunc and concretefunc had both the same name func. Why wouldn't it work with overloaded methods? (and how can I appropriately change my post?

Comment: "_explicit type casted_" there is no cast here, only a reference binding, which does a derived to based implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
template < class T > class B : A < T > {
//                             ^^^^^^^
```

You're using private inheritance. Add a `public` should fix it.

```
template < class T > class B : public A < T > {
```

(Also, you should add `public:` inside A and B so that the methods can be accessible outside.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Forgot to set the classifiers in my dummy example. But in my actual code, public was already there. So that didn't solve the problem. (I hope my dummy code is now correct).